Apify Actor is not being authorized
I am attempting to pass through some of three actors, and am returning the following errors, per actor ID. Any insight on this would be very much appreciated.

Error running Apify actor shu8hvrXbJbY3Eb9W: User was not found or authentication token is not valid

import asyncio
import os
from apify_client import ApifyClient

# Function to handle Actor calls and process results
async def run_actor_and_process_results(actor_id, actor_input):
    apify_api_token = os.getenv('APIFY_API_TOKEN', 'error-not-a-token')
    client = ApifyClient(apify_api_token)

    # Start the actor and wait for it to finish before retrieving its output
    actor_call = client.actor(actor_id).call(run_input=actor_input, wait_secs=300)

    if actor_call:
        dataset_id = actor_call['defaultDatasetId']
        results = client.dataset(dataset_id).list_items()
        return results
    else:
        print(f'Actor {actor_id} did not produce any results.')
        return None

# Main coroutine
async def main():
    # Apify actor IDs defined, add more as client needs - currently: (Instagram, Reddit, Facebook)
    actor_ids = ['shu8hvrXbJbY3Eb9W', 'FgJtjDwJCLhRH9saM', 'qgl7gVMdjLUUrMI5P']
    
    # for loop implementing actor IDs as above. 
    for actor_id in actor_ids:
        # Ask for user inputs
        enterprise_name = input("Enterprise Name: ")
        keywords_input = input("Keyword(s) to search for (comma-separated): ")
        insight_request = input("Type of insight to ask about your data: ")

        # Split the input string into individual keywords
        keywords = [keyword.strip() for keyword in keywords_input.split(',')]

        # Concatenate the keywords into a single string separated by spaces to form the hashtag
        hashtag = ' '.join(keywords)

        # Prompt user for specific websites or use default
        search_websites = input("Do you want to search over specific websites? (yes/no): ")
        
        # if else loop taking in user website requirements.
        if search_websites.lower() == 'yes':
            websites = input("Enter specific websites (comma-separated): ").split(',')
        else:
            websites = ['https://apify.com']  # Default websites to search

        # Prepare input for Apify actor
        actor_input = {
            'start_urls': [{'url': website.strip()} for website in websites],
            'max_depth': 1  # Adjust depth as needed
        }

        # Run the Apify actor and wait for results
        try:
            results = await run_actor_and_process_results(actor_id, actor_input)
            if results:
                print(f'Actor {actor_id} finished successfully!')
                print('Results:')
                
                # Iterate over the ListPage object and print the items
                for item in results.items:
                    print(f"Item ID: {item['id']}")
                    print(f"Item URL: {item['url']}")
                    print(f"Item Title: {item['title']}")
                    print(f"Item Text: {item['text']}")
                    print("---")
                
                # Additional processing of results can be done here
                # ...

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error running Apify actor {actor_id}: {e}")

# Run the main coroutine if this script is executed
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())


I was expecting an output connecting to the Apify API and return a result.
